# ScandiPWA filter by "category_uid" always returns all products in GraphQL queries

Tags: magento, graphql, progressive-web-apps

Situation:

Fresh Magento Installation and fresh/working ScandiPWA Installation.

Problem:

GraphQL query for "products" with the filter "category_uid" always returns all products of all categories, even if I filter for non-existing "category_uid".

Example GraphQL query:

```
{
  products(
    filter: { category_uid: {eq: "Nw==" } }
  ) {
    items {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Why I think this is a ScandyPWA Problem?

Because on a fresh Magento installation (before ScandiPWA installation) the query above is working.

Why I need a solution for this Problem?

Because the category Filter (checkboxes in layered navigation) uses "category_uid" instead of "category_id",
for example:

```
http://my_domain.com/clothing.html?customFilters=category_uid:NA==
```

I found out that ScandiPWA overrides/extends some Magento GraphQL code.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this problem?

Comment: Hi @fulma_joe ! 
I'll try to help you today, I have found the same issue and will check the ScandiPWA code

Have you opened an issue on ScandiPWA GitHub?


Found issue :) https://github.com/scandipwa/scandipwa/issues/5454